# Difficulty relating to the pullback of a divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading a section in Shafarevich's "Basic Algebraic Geometry I" where he discusses the pullback if a divisor.

> Let $ \varphi: X \rightarrow Y $ be a regular map of nonsingular irreducible varieties, and $ D $ be a divisor on $ Y. $ Suppose that $ \varphi(X) \not\subset \text{Supp}(D). $ We prove that under this restriction, one can define the pullback $ \varphi^{*}(D) $ if a divisor $ D $ by analogy with the definition of the pullback of a regular function. 
>   First, we determine when we can construct the pullback of a rational function $ f $ on $ Y, $ and when it will not be identically zero on $ X. $ For this, it will be sufficient that there is at least one point $ y \in \varphi(X) $ at which $ f $ is regular and $ f(y) \neq 0. $ The  points where this is true, form a nonempty open set $ V $ where $ f $ is regular and nowhere vanishing on $ V. $

I'm alright with this so far. The author goes on:

> Therefore, $ \varphi^{*}(f) $ defines a regular function on $ \varphi^{-1}(V) $ that is not identically $ 0 $ (in fact nowhere $ 0$). Since $ \varphi^{-1}(V) $ is open in $ X,\; \varphi^{*}(f) $ defines a rational function on $ X. $

I guess I agree with this, if $ \varphi^{*}(f) = f \circ \varphi. $

I'm having some trouble with the following statement:

> In terms of divisors our condition on the map $ \varphi $ and the function $ f $ boil down to $ \varphi(X) \not\subset \text{Supp}( \operatorname{div}f). $

Comment: If $\varphi(X)\subset \operatorname{Supp}(div f)$, then $\varphi^*(f)=0$, which is what we want to avoid.

Comment: Got it. $ \varphi^{*}(f) = 0 $ precisely because the image of X is contained in some union of codimension 1 subvarieties of  Y.